# Android 7.0 Migration - Handling FileUriExposedException when accessing android_asset folder

Tags: android, android-webview, assets, android-7.0-nougat, android-fileprovider

## Background

After migrating to Android 7.0 I noticed my app was crashing with a `FileUriExposedException` when loading the following url in my webView:

```
webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/myFolder/myFile.html")
```

I read [here](https://proandroiddev.com/sharing-files-though-intents-are-you-ready-for-nougat-70f7e9294a0b) that this occurs because of some file system permission changes introduced in Android 7.0 where a `FileUriExposedException` is now thrown when trying to share a file:// Uri in an Intent.

I tried to implement the suggested work around which was to use a `FileProvider` for temporary access permissions ([here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.html#Permissions)), but I do not know of a way to make this work for the `android_asset` folder as I only see that the available paths for the `FileProvider` involve the internal and external storage paths.

## Code

From MainActivity ->

```
  Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), HelpActivity.class);
  startActivity(intent);
```

From HelpActivity ->

```
 webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/help/index.html");
```

## Question

Does anyone know a good way to get around this exception when needing to load a file from the assets folder in the webView?

```
android.os.FileUriExposedException: file:///android_asset/help/help.html exposed beyond app through Intent.getData()
      at android.os.StrictMode.onFileUriExposed(StrictMode.java:1958)
      at android.net.Uri.checkFileUriExposed(Uri.java:2348)
      at android.content.Intent.prepareToLeaveProcess(Intent.java:9766)
      at android.content.Intent.prepareToLeaveProcess(Intent.java:9720)
      at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1609)
      at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4472)
      at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityJB.startActivityForResult(BaseFragmentActivityJB.java:50)
      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:79)
      at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4430)
      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:859)
      at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4791)
      at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4759)
      at android.content.ContextWrapper.startActivity(ContextWrapper.java:366)
      at org.chromium.android_webview.ResourcesContextWrapperFactory$WebViewContextWrapper.startActivity(ResourcesContextWrapperFactory.java:118)
      at org.chromium.android_webview.AwContentsClient.sendBrowsingIntent(AwContentsClient.java:203)
      at org.chromium.android_webview.AwContentsClient.shouldIgnoreNavigation(AwContentsClient.java:170)
      at org.chromium.android_webview.AwContentsClientBridge.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(AwContentsClientBridge.java:352)
      at org.chromium.base.SystemMessageHandler.nativeDoRunLoopOnce(Native Method)
      at org.chromium.base.SystemMessageHandler.handleMessage(SystemMessageHandler.java:41)
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
      at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

Comment: "After migrating to Android 7.0 I noticed my app was crashing with a FileUriExposedException when loading the following url in my webView" -- seriously? Can you post the complete Java stack trace?

Comment: @CommonsWare Oops sorry about that, I added it.

Comment: The stacktrace looks more like you try to pass that file uri in the intent used by startActivity().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Web content appears to contain something that is triggering the `WebView` to go load `help.html` via some relative path. The default behavior of a `WebView` is to ask the default Web browser to load that page. That will not work for `file:///android_asset/` `Uri` values.

So, review the HTML, figure out what is trying to redirect to `help.html`, and fix it. Also, consider adding a `WebViewClient` to your `WebView`, where you can control this sort of page-loading behavior via `shouldOverrideUrlLoading()`.

Comment: Thanks! I added a `WebViewClient` to my `WebView` in my `HelpActivity` class and overrode `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` as shown below: `webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() { @Override public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView webView, String url) { webView.loadUrl(url); return true; }` that fixed the issue I was having. However, I don't exactly understand why this wasn't necessary prior to updating to Nougat.  (Also, like you said the html contains relative paths in the href links)